# Update hostname of SVN working copy

Tags: svn

I have a working copy of some source code checked out from SVN - problem is IT has moved the subversion machine and offered a hostname for us to use from now and into the future.  How can I update my working copy with the new hostname for the subversion machine?

Currently, the working copy tries to communicate with the old SVN machine IP address and it times out because the machine is no longer there.

Any ideas?  I know I can find this out there on the intertubes but I am having the hardest time getting the wording correctly in my searches.  Using the terms 'update hostname svn working copy' are not getting me there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the command line you use the "switch" command.

See [this](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re27.html) for an example of command line use:

`svn switch --relocate file:///tmp/repos file:///tmp/newlocation`

TortoiseSVN provides a shortcut for this command called "Relocate..."

Comment: Thank you!  Using 'svn info' i was able to get the root of my project and copy its url location to the new location.  "svn switch --relocate ORIGINAL_URL NEW_URL"